# Performance issues with Sonata Admin entity listing

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I am using Symfony2 and Sonata Admin Bundle but I am encountering performance issues with entity listing in edit mode.

I have an article entity, and those articles can be linked to multiple biographies (~ 100 000 biographies in database).

Here is a part of my ArticleAdmin.php class.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('biographies', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'SJBiographyBundle:Biography',
            'multiple' => true
        ))
    ->end();
}
```

This generates a select with my 100 000 biographies when I am editing my article (and it works fine), except that loading 100 000 objects from the database takes a lot of time.

With the latest version of Sonata Admin Bundle, the select comes with an autocompletion field.

**My question is:** is there any way to load only 50 or 100 biographies and to load more by filtering with the autocompletion field?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `sonata_type_model_list`, see related documentation: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html#advanced-usage-many-to-one